# PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'New.Id'

Tags: visual-studio-2010, oracle

I know it is very common issue and have read multiple resources on the same but could not  fix it.
I'm using `Query Window` within `Visual Studio`

**Trigger**:

```
TRIGGER "CERTCATID_TRIG"
  BEFORE
  INSERT
  ON "CertCategoryValues"
  FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN -- executable part starts here
  SELECT SEQ_CERTCAT.NEXTVAL 
  INTO :new.id
  FROM dual;

END;
```

**Table**
CertCategoryValues table with id column but still getting same error.

[image: Table]

**ERROR**  .CERTCATID_TRIG' is invalid and failed re-validation

Comment: Try naming tables and columns (and constraints, indexes, triggers, etc) with all UPPERCASE letters. Then you're trigger should work as you've written it. If you use lowercase for Oracle objects, you'll have to surround object names with quotes (") and match the case exactly to get it to work.

Comment: @GriffeyDog, Thank you so much. Putting in Quotes worked. Can you rewrite this in Answer, I will mark it as answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Answer by @GriffeyDog in comments** *Hope this helps someone*

"If you use lowercase for Oracle objects, you'll have to surround object names with quotes (") and match the case exactly to get it to work."

It worked.

```
TRIGGER "CERTCATID_TRIG"
  BEFORE
  INSERT
  ON "CertCategoryValues"
  FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN -- executable part starts here
  SELECT SEQ_CERTCAT.NEXTVAL 
  INTO :new."id"
  FROM dual;
END;
```